# fatal error: 'X11/Xlib.h' file not found

Tags: linker, x11, xlib

I have installed XQuartz.
I compiled using g++:

```
g++ -o -lX11 -I/opt/X11/include window2.cc
```

**Error**

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:

"_XCreateWindow", referenced from:
  _main in window2-dXb9bZ.o
 "_XFlush", referenced from:
  _main in window2-dXb9bZ.o
"_XMapWindow", referenced from:
  _main in window2-dXb9bZ.o
"_XOpenDisplay", referenced from:
  _main in window2-dXb9bZ.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

If i compile like this:

```
g++ window2.cc -o window -lX11 -I/opt/X11/include
```

**Error**

```
ld: library not found for -lX11
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Im sure Xlib.h is in /opt/X11/include

Code:

```
#include <X11/Xlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
  {
  // Open a display.
  Display *d = XOpenDisplay(0);

 if ( d )
{
  // Create the window
  Window w = XCreateWindow(d, DefaultRootWindow(d), 0, 0, 200,
                           100, 0, CopyFromParent, CopyFromParent,
                           CopyFromParent, 0, 0);

  // Show the window
  XMapWindow(d, w);
  XFlush(d);

  // Sleep long enough to see the window.
  sleep(10);
}
 return 0;
 }
```

How do I solve this problem ? Thanks in advance

Comment: How is the title related to the error given in the question? I'd say you have to install the X11 headers (according to your title) and the X11 library (according to your question). This might help you: http://support.apple.com/kb/ht5293 If you use macports you can install xorg-libX11

Comment: what do you have on LD_LIBRARY_PATH?

Comment: I have Xlib.h in /opt/X11/include

Answer (score 1):

Problem resolved. In case anyone who's interested:
You have to compile like this:

```
g++ -o window window.cc -I/usr/X11R6/include -L/usr/X11R6/lib -lX11
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
cc -I /opt/X11/include/ test.c -L /opt/X11/lib -lX11
```